# Drawing a wheel in raphaeljs

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to make the so called fine tune thing. Basically this looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/r9KQK/1/

Later I'll have some audio player and this thing will help to select seconds when we use it on a tablet.

The problem is when you try to move the red circle it strangely drops when it passes top and bottom of the green circle, but not at 0 or PI/2, something like at -260..-269 and 181..190 degrees

Just try to move it and you'll see the bug.

What's wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance

**update**

Last update: http://jsfiddle.net/r9KQK/17/

In this example I get degrees in 0..360 range. But instead I should get delta degrees between the point where I start dragging and where I end it, but I can't work out the maths. I should also take into account the direction of red circle, so that delta will be + or - =\

**update**

Finally: http://jsfiddle.net/r9KQK/18/

But the code is really awful. Though it's 2:46 AM and I'm kind of sleepy, so...
But anyway I think it could be much more simplified

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's happening because your parameter to Math.atan goes to infinity when DeltaX is zero.  I recommend using atan2, which automatically handles this corner case:

```
function(dx, dy, x, y) 
{
    var deltaY = this.oy + dy - fineTuning.ring.attr('cy');
    var deltaX = this.ox + dx - fineTuning.ring.attr('cx');
    var angle = Math.atan2( deltaY, deltaX );

    // etcetera, etcetera
```

Or check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/9uwFG/).

Comment: Oh, thanks, never heard about atan2 function. Actually I thought that it's not the infinity problem because there were several points when the red circle dropped. But I have another issue: I updated my jsfiddle example, and all I want to achieve is to make "fine-tuning". In the end it must look like I rotate the red circle in both directions and get slowly +N or -N, like trying to erm... lets say get a necessary frequency on my reciever. But look I think   the mechanism is wrong: in my example I get degrees only from 0 to 360, so it's hard to work with these degrees =(

Comment: Well here's a question -- will the fine tuning control be used in conjunction with "coarse" tuning control?  I.e., one control to adjust the frequency from 88.0 to 108.0 in intervals of 0.2, and then the fine tuning control to adjust within the 0.2 interval space?  What sort of units were you planning on using it against?

Comment: Actually I'll have a tablet with opened browser with audio player. I'll select for example 2:23 by my finger and then using this wheel I'll add or decrease some seconds. Lets say that the full rotation CW will add 5 seconds. I'm trying to make it, though there are a lot of problems with degrees, and the code becomes more and more messy...Tomorrow I'll try to finish it but seems like my solution is not the best :)